# jQuery.Deferred exception - unrequested call to event handler

Tags: jquery, ajax, events

I am working on an application which makes extensive use of AJAX and jQuery events, and have run into odd behavior which I am unable to explain. A doctored version of the offending snippet:

```
$(document).on("app.refresh", function(jqEvent) {
    //app.server.get returns an AJAX promise
    app.server.get("url/goes/here").
        done(function(result) { $(document).trigger("app.refresh.done", [result]); }).
        fail(function() { $(document).trigger("app.refresh.fail"); });
}

$(document).on("app.refresh.done", function(jqEvent, result) {
    if (result.success)
        cache(result.data);
}

$(function() {
    $(document).trigger("app.refresh");
});
```

The handler for `"app.refresh.done"` executes *twice*. The second time it executes the stack shows the call coming from `$(document).trigger("app.refresh");`, uses the data returned by the AJAX call to fill `result`, and completes without error. The first time it executes, however:

- No request is made to the server (a breakpoint placed at the endpoint being accessed via AJAX will not be hit)
- As the server is not accessed `result` is `undefined`, resulting in an error on the line `if (result.success)`:

  > jQuery.Deferred exception: result is not defined ReferenceError: result is not defined
- The stack at time of execution shows that the call does not originate from the trigger. It originates from a function in jQuery called `mightThrow` contained in a function called `process`.

Further confounding my efforts to figure out what is going on is the fact that changing the event names to `"refresh.begin"`, `"refresh.done"`, and `"refresh.fail"` fixes the problem entirely. What the heck is causing the erroneous first call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through the relevant documentation it's become obvious that this is a problem caused by the way `.on()` and `.trigger()` handle [event namespacing](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names). In summary:

- Periods in event names such as `"app.refresh.done"` make jQuery apply namespaces to the events.
- The event name comes first, followed by the namespaces, which are *not hierarchical* and work similarly to CSS classes. `"app.refresh.done"` represents an "app" event that is in both the "refresh" and "done" namespaces.
- When triggering an event, all events that match the event name and exist in the specified namespace(s) are triggered. Triggering `"app.refresh"` will fire all "app" events in the "refresh" namespace.

In the above code `"app.refresh"`, `"app.refresh.done"`, and `"app.refresh.fail"` are called when `"app.refresh"` is triggered - they are all "app" events in the "refresh" namespace.

I've created [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/dp08naq5/1/) on JSFiddle to illustrate.